# Отправка письма через PHP

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток! Возник такой вопрос. Прошу совета. Мне для сайта срочно понадобился простенький скриптик для отправки письма со странички. Порывшись в Нете, я нашел один, очень простой. Он работает. Только хотелось бы его чуть усовершенствовать, но незнание в PHP не позволяет.

В страничке находится два текстовых поля и кнопка submit. Собственно скрипт

```
 <?php

if($_POST['submit']) {

        $title = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['title'])), 0, 1000);
        $mess =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mess'])), 0, 1000000);

        $to = 'моя почта';

        $from=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// вышестоящая хренотень пишет в адресе письма IP пользователя, больше никуда не смог ее втиснуть.

        mail($to, $title, $mess, 'From:'.$from);
        echo("<script>location.href='http:/главная страница'</script>");
    // а это шлет нас после отправки обратно на главную страничку сайта.

}
?>
```

И у меня такой вопрос - как можно сделать, чтобы в теле письма в начале подписывался текст "Форма отправки сообщения". Знаю, что вопрос тупой, и что тут все решается, скорее всего, на уровне операторов, но в PHP я не соображаю ровным счетом ничего, пытался изучить, но не подействовало.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правы, все просто =)

Переменная $mess хранит тело письма.

Нужный текст добавляется оператором конкатенации "."

```
$mess =  "Форма отправки сообщения: " . substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['mess'])), 0, 1000000);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! А если, к примеру,я хочу добавить в тело письма значение какой-нибудь еще переменной, как тогда прописывать код?
переменная уже объявлена.

Comment: а всё, разобрался)))

Comment: если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста, отметьте его как верный. (слева под пальчиком вниз есть галочка)